# Test if element is in a list and return 0 or 1

Tags: r, performance, loops

I am currently trying to check if an element is part of a list and return 1 if it's the case and 0 otherwise.

I have been doing a loop for this but as the matrix are going to be very big (here only a simple example is provided) I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do it.

```
rm(list=ls())   # clear memory
names <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k50","l50","m50","n50","o50")

proba <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)

T1_temp <- sample(names,4,prob=proba)

# Loop to check which element of T1_temp is included in names
T1 <- c()
for (i in 1:length(names)){
  if (is.element(names[i],T1_temp)){T1[i]=1}
  else{T1[i]=0}
}
```

and the results are

```
 [1] 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: @Donkey Kong thanks for your reshaping my question and thanks jogo for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `%in%`

```
as.integer(names %in% T1_temp)
```

Or `match`

```
 +(!is.na(match(names,T1_temp)))
```

Comment: thanks for the rapidity of your answer (about 1 min after my question, it's amazing). and this is perfect. It's exactly what i wanted in order to avoid many loops.

Comment: @ akrun sure I just had to wait 10 minutes :) enjoy